# Why CorsConfigurationSource's is ignored, no Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My goal is to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origins` in the header.

The Spring Security Reference's clearly said to

1. Set a POJO as @EnableWebSecurity's bean.
2. Override a configure(HttpSecurity http) method.
3. Create a CorsConfigurationSource's bean.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .cors(withDefaults())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
  }

  @Bean
  protected CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

  @GetMapping("/ping")
  public String getPing() {
    return "PONG";
  }
}
```

What I did:

1. Run a Spring Boot's application with the above configuration
2. Send a Fetch request to `http://localhost:8080/ping` from a React client.

The actual result:

1. The response does not include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I think it should be in the OPTIONS request.

The expected result:

1. A success response.

I am confused... I did a curl and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present. I think there is something wrong with the client side handling the HttpBasic.

```
curl -v -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" -X OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/ping
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS /ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Origin: http://localhost:3000
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2021 13:37:15 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: What does the console in the webbrowser tell you when you do your fetch request

Comment: @Toerktumlare umm it's a silly mistake. I forgot to allow `authorization` header in the Spring Security.